# Example of a local homeomorphism that does not have the path lifting property.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am looking for an example of a local homeomorphism $p:X \to Y$, that does not have the path lifting property.

I demand $X$ and $Y$ be path-connected, Hausdorff.

Note: I am asking this question out of curiosity. So I have no idea how difficult this might be.

Comment: Take your favourite connected Hausdorff space and consider the inclusion of a connected open subset such that it's complement is non empty. Now take an arbitrary path with starting point in the open subset and end point in its complement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $p : (0,2\pi +1) \to S^1, p(t) = e^{it}$. Now try to lift the path $u : I \to S^1, u(t) = e^{it}$.